# Building php v5.6.9 for use with Apache 2.4 on CentOS 6.6

Tags: redhat, scl

I'm using Webtactic's PHP 5.6.9 src rpm to build a Software Collection version of PHP that I can use with Apache 2.4 on Centos 6.6.

Andy Thompson has already written all the SCL RPM macros into the spec file making this task quite straight forward.

However my understanding is SCL applications are intended to reside in their own directory structure with separate init scripts et al. To use an SCL apaplication one adjusts ones path with the enable script supplied with the SCL application.

But this means libphp569-php5.so is stored in /opt/rh/php569/.... not in /opt/rh/https24/....

What is the preferred way to setup SCL so that Apache 2.4 can use PHP 5.6.9?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, it seems I miss the question.

The PHP 5.6 Software collection already exists, see:

- https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/?search=php (PHP version 5.6.5 with mod_php for httpd24 as SCL)
- http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2014/08/25/PHP-5.6-as-Software-Collection (PHP version 5.6.15 with mod_php for httpd in base system)

I think the preferred way to get Apache 2.4 to use PHP is to use the SetHandler to fastcgi proxy feature, and php-fpm.